# Add question geotagging to certain sites (Travel, Outdoors, Gardening)

Tags: feature-request

For some SE sites, adding a geographical location to questions would make a lot of sense. Namely, Travel.SE (where localized questions are explicitly allowed) and the new Outdoors.SE (ditto).

It would work just like the "Location" field in your profile: You can enter a region*, or a specific location.

Once enough data has been collected, there is a plentitude of things that one could do with it:

- Most obviously, displaying a huge, cool Google Map.
- Providing map layers for Google Earth and the like.
- Providing layers for mobile applications.
- a "Questions on places near you" feature

Random examples:

- [3 days in London. What do I absolutely have to see?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/3-days-in-london-what-do-i-absolutely-have-to-see) on Travel.SE
- [Are there currently any international ferries that travel to Saint Petersburg, Russia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/489/are-there-currently-any-international-ferries-that-travel-to-saint-petersburg-r) on Travel.SE
- [Is it legal to camp on private property in Russia?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-legal-to-camp-on-private-property-in-russia) on Outdoors.SE

*: Entering a region (that is a rectangle or polygon instead of an exact lat/lon location) creates the question how to deal with them visually later - the most straightforward thing to plot on a map is coordinates; displaying *areas* is much harder. Maybe the range of options would have to be limited to either specifying a *country name*, or a lat/lon coordinate. You could then later list the per-country questions, and display everything else as dots on the map.

Comment: hmm I wonder if there's a way to use the location based tags in some way , [london] and [russia] in your examples

Comment: @Conrad I thought of the same thing, but I think it would create a huge mess - you'd have loads of place, region, country and continent name tags, and no reliable way to geocode them

Comment: gardening might also benefit from this. Questions about winterhardiness, plant identification, and timing of planting/blooming/harvest are all highly location-specific.

Comment: @Kate good point. Gardening might  specifically benefit from specifying *regions*

Comment: Gardening's US users would probably benefit with both the [USDA Hardiness Zones](http://www.garden.org/zipzone/) and the [Sunset climate zones](http://www.sunset.com/garden/climate-zones/climate-zones-intro-us-map-00400000036421/). Both zone systems are in wide use on plant information sheets, nursery growing and planting guides, and university extension programs. I don't know if these zone systems have good international equivalents. (Which is important if you're going to be farming reputation points in Germany.)

Comment: Certainly for travel, a tag **hierarchy** for location tags seems obvious; but that concept has been generally disfavoured here on meta...

Comment: Travel.SE does allow questions about specific locations but it does not allow questions which are "too localized" by Stack Exchange's definition of that term.

Comment: Hierarchies sound good and makes sense for travel.SE in a way, but I feel they are much harder to implement and to get right than plain old lists. Look at categories on Wikipedia for an example of somewhere hierarchies seem logical but just cannot work as things currently are there.

Comment: Gardening would definitely make good use of this. We have been looking for some way to add location easily to questions for some time now.

Answer (score 6):

This is a great idea!

I would like to add that at least in the case of travel.SE that some questions specifically include more than one specific location so some ways to implement it may be better. I'm thinking:

- list of geotags per QA
- list of geotags per post, ie ability to apply them to each answer as well as the question
- geotag in markup. Much like we can select a section of text to apply a URL to we could also apply a geotag to a selection of text so we can tag each location, site, etc right where it is mentioned in the post

Answer (score 2):

A "region" could *possibly* be as simple as a *pair* of coordinates that are the topLeft-bottomRight corners of a rectangle. It constrains areas/regions to just a simple rectangle, but it's much less complex than political or geographic regions from a "shape" standpoint.

I'm not sure having such a simple "region" is all that useful, unfortunately, but it may be a good balance between simplicity and functionality.